# Iterating through a list using for loops in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could someone please explain why the following is happening please?

```
>>> ls = ['a', 'b']
>>> for i in ls:
...    ls.remove(i)
...
>>> ls
['b']
>>> ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for i in ls:
...    ls.remove(i)
...
>>> ls
[2, 4]
```

I would expect the for loop to run through every element in the list, and remove it, leaving me with an empty list. Why does the first list end up with one element left, and the second example seems to have lost all the odd numbers? How should I do this instead? Thanks! :)

Comment: Please paste your code into your question, then highlight it and click the code formatting button.

Comment: Don't post code as images.

Comment: Do not modify a list while iterating over it with a `for` loop in Python. You screw up the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's show the second example, it's easier to see what's going on.

- Take the first element: `1`
- Remove it; the list is now `[2, 3, 4, 5]`
- Take the second element: `3`
- Remove it; the list is now `[2, 4, 5]`
- Take the third element: `5`
- Remove it; the list is now `[2, 4]`
- Next element would be the fourth element, but the list only has two; terminate.

The point to note is that in each iteration, you're not getting the `n`-th element of the list as it was in past, before the loop started; you're getting the `n`-th element of the array as it is in that moment.

The first example is the same, just stops sooner.

The Pythonic way to clear a list:

```
del ls[:]
```

EDIT: To conditionally delete elements, the most Pythonic way is to make a new filtered list:

```
filtered_ls = [x for x in ls if okay(x)]
```

If you want to not lose reference to the old list, you can do this:

```
filtered_ls[:] = [x for x in ls if okay(x)]
```

And finally, you can also iterate from the back; this way, since you're always working on the last element, removing it doesn't screw up the list.

Comment: I see.. Thank you! Let's say I wanted to apply a condition to each value of the list, and remove it if it does not satisfy it, how should I proceed?

Comment: @Windmill Please refer to the question I linked in my comment on your question. I know the title doesn't sound similar but that is the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: @Windmill: Usually, the easiest way it to use a `list` comprehension and replace the original `list` with the result. `mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, `mylist = [x for x in mylist if x % 2 == 0]` would be an example of filtering to remove odd values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through a list item-by-item and remove them, use a `while` loop:

```
>>> ls=['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> while ls:
...    e=ls.pop()
...    print e
... 
c
b
a
>>> ls
[]
```

If you want that to be performant, use  [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for faster pop's